# L2S Approach for Interface Property

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

We're using L2S and we have a class like this:

```
public class HumanContainer
{
    public List<IHuman> Humans { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**Our database has tables like this:**
HumanContainer
 - Geek

We've only had one type of Human so far (Geek). And when we send/retrieve HumanContainers to/from the DB, we know to treat them as Geeks. Now that we need a second Human (Athlete), we have a choice to make for how to implement this.

**One option is to create another table (Athlete) in the DB:**
HumanContainer
 - Geek
 - Athlete

For every new concrete Human like this, we'll need to loop through HumanContainer.Humans, detect the type, add it to the appropriate EntitySet<>, then save.

**Another option is to have only one table for all Humans:**
HumanContainer
 - Humans

If we do that, then we'll need something like an XML column where we serialize the Human into its specific type and store it in that column. Then we'll need to deserialize that column when retrieving the data.

Is one of the approaches recommended? I'm curious to know how people have been handling this situation. Is there a third approach that I haven't listed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like you are trying to do is represent inheritance in a relational database. [Guy Burstein](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/) has a pair of great articles on this subject: [How To: Model Inheritance in Databases](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/09/30/how-to-model-inheritance-in-databases.aspx) and [Linq to SQL Inheritance](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/01/linq-to-sql-inheritance.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. Those are good articles for how L2S natively handles this. I could still write my own mapping layer if I want to use multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand properly your question, In your case It's possible to have different type of humans in future. You can try following solution.

Solution 1:

As you mentioned only create One Table in Database 'Humas' and serialize the Human into specific Type and store it in that column and deserialize that column when retrieving the data. This solution seems good because If need to any Human type in future we don't need to change database design. and easy to manage.

But The dis advantage of this solution is that if application required only Geek Humans type then first need to retrieve column data and deserialize it and after that we can find Geek Human type.

Solution 2:

Create Two table in database. 
1) HumanType : for save Type of human (Geek, Athlete, or any other Type)
2) Human : storing Human information. This table contain reference key of HumanType.

The Advantage of this solution is that you can easily fire query based on requirement (e.g Only Geek Type Human easily fetched from table). and if any new Human Type come then one entry required to enter in HumanType Database.